# Are there any tools or components for jLogger?

Tags: logs

I use jLogger a great deal, but get tired of constantly opening an editor, finding the file, etc. etc.. Is there a way I should be looking at these files, or is there a tool that I'm not aware of?  It seems there is a lot of work behind the classes involved, and not much there to use the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well with the complete absence of even comments, I don't expect that too many folks will be interested.  I put together a class that extends JLog by writing logs to the database instead of text files.  I then used a free component builder to put together a component to view that data.  The resulting component works rather nicely, but is a compilation of tweaks and experiments on top of some bloated base code to see what might be possible.

It can be downloaded from the [JSE Github](https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange/glogger).  Constructive feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for sharing this, it looks really useful!

Comment: I hope so....I TRULY have to apologize for the code though.   It was just cut/paste and inserting code wherever it was convenient at the time while family was visiting over the long weekend.  I didn't really expect it to become more than just a class, and didn't have the time to build it properly

Comment: Sometimes that is the cost of getting things done. I won't judge :)

Comment: I appreciate that, lol...but if you're ever in a judgmental mood, that code as is will be a playground for you, lol.